# Should I let pacman replace glamor-egl with xorg-server?

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, pacman

This is the output of `pacman`. I installed nothing; just wanted to update...

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra           1761.1 KiB  2.58M/s 00:01 [#######################################################################] 100%
 community          2.3 MiB  2.25M/s 00:01 [#######################################################################] 100%
 multilib         121.2 KiB  1236K/s 00:00 [#######################################################################] 100%
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace glamor-egl with extra/xorg-server? [Y/n]
```

What could cause this? What option should I select?

Comment: For future reference, it's good to check [the Arch news](https://www.archlinux.org/news/) before you `pacman -Syu`. Some updates need user-intervention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's not a conflict, its a reflection of the fact that the new version of X (1.16) has hit the repos and, as [the news makes clear](https://www.archlinux.org/news/xorg-server-116-is-now-available/), `glamour-egl` is deprecated.

Follow `pacman`'s advice and select `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a conflict. That same thing happened to me today. But that just means that the package has been deprecated and to replace the dependencies of that package, you download that other one.

Comment: How does this add anything to the answer I provided, other than to inculde personal anecdote?